# Solving a matrix equation involving a square root

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find the $n \times 1$ vector $x$ solution to the problem

$$(A+A^{1/2})x = b$$

where $A$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite (full rank) real matrix, $A^{1/2}$ is **the** (edit: as it is SPD) matrix such that $A^{1/2} A^{1/2} = A$, and $b$ is a known $n \times 1$ vector. I have access to $A$, but not $A^{1/2}$. I could compute the eigenpairs of $A$ to find $A^{1/2}$, but this would be expensive so I would rather find an alternative.

Can anyone think of/point me to another method for finding $x$ rather than finding the eigenpairs?

Comment: [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) describes a few methods of calculating $A^{1/2}$ that don't involve diagonalization, including two methods that appear designed to be computationally efficient.  While your problem may still have an easier theoretical answer, the linked page (likely) is a better default solution than diagonalization.

Comment: Thanks Mark. These methods seem to require a matrix solve each iteration, which is also computationally expensive ($O(n^3)$), but might be a good idea if somehow there was a way to do that cheaply.